# How to forward data packets through an alternative path via an alternative parent?

Tags: parent, packet, contiki, cooja

For example, We have a **RPL** tree, and several *data senders* transmitting data packets to the *sink*. **After a while**, one of the senders stops sending or forwarding data to parent node because we assumed the parent node is suspicious. Instead of sending or forwarding the data packet via the suspicious node, it forwards the data packet through an **alternative path** via an **alternative parent** that is chosen from the *parent list*. What is an efficient and *simple way* to implement this scenario in Contiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to blacklist a specific parent (or multiple parents). To achieve that, you can add a new field `uint8_t is_suspicious` to the `struct rpl_parent`.

I assume that you have the logic for setting this flags already in place.  Then, when doing the parent selection in RPL (the `best_parent` function in `rpl-dag.c`) you can look at the flag and exclude parents that have it set.

To the `if` condition in the existing code:

```
/* Exclude parents from other DAGs or announcing an infinite rank */
if(p->dag != dag || p->rank == INFINITE_RANK || p->rank < ROOT_RANK(dag->instance)) {
  if(p->rank < ROOT_RANK(dag->instance)) {
    PRINTF("RPL: Parent has invalid rank\n");
  }
  continue;
}
```

you would add another check: `... || p->is_suspicious)`.

Finally, you need to re-trigger the parent selection algorithm every time the `is_suspicious` status changes of a parent. One way to do that is to call the function `rpl_process_parent_event`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kfx. I changed condition statement **Search for the best parent according to the OF** in _best_parent_ function in _rpl-dag.c_ like this:
`for(...; p != NULL && rpl_get_parent_ipaddr(p)->u8[15] != suspicious_node_id;...)`. I think it's work perfectly, isn't it?

Comment: It will certainly work. Having a flag in the `rpl_parent` structure is still better stylistically, as that way you can have multiple "suspicious" nodes.

Comment: Your answer certainly work, but I'm using `node_id` in my _C_ project file and will add a `uint8_t is_suspicious` flag to **struct rpl_parent** in **rpl.h**. How do I set or change `p->is_suspicious` flag when I find out my suspicious `node_id` in _C_ project file? I need `.. || p->is_suspicious` but this flag not assign it before.